# Javascript Date() parameters for constructor

Tags: javascript, date

Let's say I want to create a date-object for 2012 Sep 1st, 10:11:15 h.

I figured out:

```
past = new Date(2012,08,01,10,11,15);// works!
past = new Date('2012,08,01,10,11,15');// doesn't work.
```

The problem is, I want to use it in combination with a method:

```
past = new Date(mypastformatfunc(mystring_to_format));
```

This gives me NaN. No valid Date-object created.
I checked the return of the mypastformatfunc() and it seems I have the right format. Is there any escaping problem regarding quotes?
How can I get this to work? It's really strange...
Thanks.

EDIT SOLVED:
Problem was it wasn't a one value but single parameters. They can't be passed by a function's return at once....

Comment: Can you post the code for `mypastformatfunc` so we can see exactly what it returns?

Answer (score 2):

Use the date string as the parameter to the constructor.

```
past = new Date('2012,08,01,10,11,15'.replace(/(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+)/, '$1/$2/$3 $4:$5:$6'));

function mypastformatfunc(str) {
  return str.replace(/(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+)/, '$1/$2/$3 $4:$5:$6')
}
```